# How do I pass parameters to a subroutine?

Tags: perl, syntax

I have encountered a difficulty in understanding the subroutine syntax.

using the following code:

```
sub build_dyne_file{
open(DYNAP, "+>$veri_dir/$dyna_para") or die $!;
    for (keys %hash){
        print DYNAP "#define ",$_," ",$hash{$_}->[$i],"\n";
    }
    close(DYNAP);
}

for (my $i = 0 ; $i <$TEST_QUOTA ; $i++){
    build_dyna_file($i);
}
```

In the 'build dyne file' subroutine, the 'for loop' iterates over the hash keys, while the $i parameter used inside the external 'for loop'.

I hope you understand the problem, If not - I'll try to explain it more properly.

thanks for any answer.

Comment: you are not asking a question. can you be more precise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to *receive* the parameter.

```
sub build_dyne_file { 
    my $i = shift; # take it off the parameter queue
    ...
```

You declared it with a *[lexical](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my())* scope in the lower for loop ( using `my` ), so therefore only that loop can "see" it. When you pass it to `build_dyne_file`, you need to receive the parameter.

Please see [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

Comment: That's "perl", not "PERL".  It's not an acronym.

Comment: Actually, when referring to the language, please use "Perl".

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `$i` parameter in your subroutine:

```
sub build_dyne_file
{
  open(DYNAP, "+>$veri_dir/$dyna_para") or die $!;

  # the crucial omission...
  my $i = shift;

    for (keys %hash){
        print DYNAP "#define ",$_," ",$hash{$_}->[$i],"\n";
    }
    close(DYNAP);
}
```

Comment: This might be a matter of preference, but I very much prefer to shift the arguments first in a subroutine (in this case before, not after, opening the file).